# What is the link_to path to a non-resourceful route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a non-resourceful route that uses a SHA token in the route. Here it is in my routes.rb file:

```
match 'permissions/confirm/:token' => 'permissions#confirm'
```

I can access the generated route, but I don't know what to pass in for the link_to helper.

Here is what I'm using for the link_to, which is not working:

```
<%= link_to "Give permission", confirm_permission_path(:token => @permission.token) %>
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add `:as` key to your route like `match 'permissions/confirm/:token' => 'permissions#confirm', :as => :confirm_permissions`

Then `<%= link_to "Give permission", confirm_permissions_path(:token => @permission.token) %>`

Comment: That seems to make sense, and it looks good when I look at `rake routes`, but I'm still getting an undefined method error: `undefined method confirm_permission_path`.

Comment: Is it just that it should be `confirm_permissions_path`, pluralized.

Comment: Yes, that seemed to be the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can always use `rake routes` to figure out what the name of a path is.  I double-check the output of that rake task all the time to make sure I'm using the correct restful or non-restful route.

Comment: `rake routes` shows that the path is `/permissions/confirm/:token(.:format)`. But I'm not sure what the link_to helper should look like for that route.

Comment: When you run `rake routes`, there are 3 columns of data. The first column is the link_to path, for example: `users_path`. The second column is the format (e.g `/users/index(.:format)`. And lastly, the third column is the action and controller (e.g `{:controller => etc ...}`. So look at that first column and you'll see the data you need.